# Phantomjs renders old image after modifying

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, image, phantomjs

I open a local page in phantomjs and update the image but the rendered version still has old image

```
// task.js
var fs = require('fs')
var page = require('webpage').create()

page.open('template.html', function(){
    page.viewportSize = {
        width: 40,
        height: 40
    }
    page.clipRect = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: 40,
        height: 40
    }

    var pageBefore = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.documentElement.innerHTML})
    fs.write('build/page-before.html', pageBefore, 'w')
    page.render('build/page-before.png')

    page.evaluate(function(){
        var bronzeCircle = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + 
            "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' stroke='none'>" + 
                "<circle fill='#D1A684' cy='10' cx='10' r='10'/>" + 
            "</svg>"
        var img = document.getElementById('img')
        img.attributes['src'].value = bronzeCircle
    })

    var pageAfter = page.evaluate(function(){
        return document.documentElement.innerHTML})
    fs.write('build/page-after.html', pageAfter, 'w')
    page.render('build/page-after.png')

    phantom.exit()
})
```

`page-before.png`:
[image: gold circle]
`page-after.png`:
[image: also gold circle]
While html files are correct.
`page-before.html`:
[image: gold circle]
`page-after.html`:
[image: bronze circle]

What is wrong here and how to make it render updated page?

---

Here is my `template.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img id='img' src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20' stroke='none'><circle fill='#FFCC01' cy='10' cx='10' r='10'/></svg>"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is `main.js` file:

```
const phantomjs = require('phantomjs-prebuilt')
var program = phantomjs.exec('task.js')
program.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
program.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
program.on('exit', code => {
    console.log('done')
})
```

I use `"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.11"`

Comment: Have you tried `img.src = bronzeCircle` instead of `img.attributes['src'].value = bronzeCircle`?

Comment: @ArtjomB. just tried. Same result

Comment: Ok, try to "asynchronize" the whole "after" block of code by using `setTimeout`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. ok, it worked with `setTimeout(after, 0)` thanks. I'd appreciate if you'd form it as a proper answer

Comment: My guess is that PhantomJS' event loop interleave resource loading with synchronous JavaScript execution. I'm not sure. If you want you can post an answer yourself.